# Show Brackets in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

when users login to their account then i show their names and also their designations it works but when i show designation it shows like mix means that username+designation for example JOHNMANAGER  .here manager is desgination and same like this happend in my side but i want designations type in brackets.
here is code

```
string desginname = Convert.ToString(loginusers.spdesignname(txt_username.Value, txt_pass.Value));
Session["UserDesignationName"] = desginname;
if (users == 1)
{
     Session["Login2"] = txt_username.Value;
     Session["Login3"] = txt_pass.Value;
     Session["UserDesignationID"] =  desginid;
      //Session["DepartmentID"] = depid; ;
     Session["UserDesignationName"] = desginname;
     Session["UserTypeID"] = users;

     Response.Redirect("alldocuments.aspx");
 }
 else if (users == 2)
 {


     Session["Login2"] = txt_username.Value;
     Session["Login3"] = txt_pass.Value;
     Session["UserDesignationID"] = desginid;
     Session["UserDesignationName"] = desginname;
     Session["UserTypeID"] = users;

     Response.Redirect("alldocuments.aspx");
  }
}           
catch
{
    errrros.Text = "Incorrect User Name or Password";
}
```

and here is in site master ...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
  if (Session["Login2"] != null & Session["UserDesignationName"]!=null) 
            {
               ["UserDesignationID"].ToString();
                WELCOME.Text = Session["Login2"].ToString()  +Session     
             [("UserDesignationName")].ToString();
            }
            lbtnLogout.Visible = Session["Login2"] != null || Session["Login2"] !=    
             null;


        }
    }
```

and here is the image
[image](http://i60.tinypic.com/nn8fgo.png)

Comment: Watch your spellings, you'll have less bugs if you get them right (eg `desginid`, `desginname`, `errrros`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them in where you build the welcome text:

```
WELCOME.Text = Session["Login2"].ToString() + " (" +  Session     
         [("UserDesignationName")].ToString() + ")";
```

or better, use `String.Format`:

```
WELCOME.Text = String.Format("{0} ({1})",
                             Session["Login2"].ToString(),
                             Session[("UserDesignationName")].ToString());
```

Comment: ok this work for me ..but you could please tell me what is the meaning of the code...this..."String.Format("{0} ({1})", "

Comment: See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). Basically `{0}` and `{1}` are place holders in the format string for the arguments to String.Format. So in this case `{0}` will be replaced by `Session["Login2"].ToString()` etc. Its a much nicer way of putting together strings as you can see the overall format much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
WELCOME.Text = Session["Login2"].ToString()  +
 " (" +  Session["UserDesignationName"].ToString() +")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use following line of code if designation name is not supplied.

```
WELCOME.Text = Session["Login2"].ToString() + (Session["UserDesignationName"].ToString()!="" ? " (" + Session["UserDesignationName"].ToString() + ")" : string.Empty) ;
```